# Return a wrapped object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have been looking at Underscores _.chain() function. I understand that it returns a wrapped object and calling methods on this object will continue to return wrapped objects until value is called. However I want to be able to do this in pure javascript but I am unsure how you would return a wrapped a object in vanilla js.

Comment: You'd need something to wrap it in.  You need to make a class, store the value in it and just have every method `return this;` while modifying the stored value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a "wrapped object" with an object that has functions that `return this`:

```
function _(xs) {
  return {
    map: function(f) {
      xs = xs.map(f)
      return this
    },
    filter: function(f) {
      xs = xs.filter(f)
      return this
    },
    value: function() {
      return xs
    }
  }
}

var result = _([1,2,3]).map(function(x) {
  return x + 1
}).filter(function(x) {
  return x < 4
}).value()

console.log(result) //=> [2, 3]
```